# Binding DevExpress DataGrid to custom datasource

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datagrid, devexpress

I'm searching for a good DataGrid implementation for a project (.NET4.0, WinForms) I'm working on. I've found DevExpress grid, which is kind of what I need, I'm just a bit lost in binding options. All the examples I was able to find were binding the grid to standard datasources - like database datasource or linq2sql... Unfortunately, I need to bind it to custom REST API to gather data from server application (with the API having the ability to specify a wide range of criteria to query the data). I also require async loading of chunks of data and not the whole dataset (few thousand of entries).

So far I have found async loading method for some DevExpress components, but all require (as far as I understood) some IQueryable interface implementation to perform the tasks.

My question is basically to find out, if there is some more sensible option to achieve this instead of implementing IQueryable set of interfaces (which I would really like not to do).

I you have some experience, please let me know. I'm not expecting working source code, just a pointers to the documentation / web sites, I probably missed or a confirmation, that I need to implement the interfaces OR some other good datagrid library with required functionality I've missed.

THANK YOU!

Comment: I've been working with Devex for a while and one of the best things is their support :) Go to their site, on the bottom right they have a live chat during business hours and an e-mail address for any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the grid.DataSource to almost any list you have, from the documentation :

Objects implementing the **IList** interface - Such data sources must have at least one "record". Otherwise, bound controls will not be able to create any rows. Controls bound to such data sources will not be notified of any data changes and thus must be updated manually.

Objects implementing the **ITypedList** interface - In this case, it is not necessary to have any "records" for rows to be created. Data change notifications are not supported.

Objects implementing the **IBindingList** interface (derived from the IList) - This data source type does not have the shortcomings of the other interfaces. The interface declares the ListChanged event, which is used by the control to update itself when bound data is changed.